# Rails AJAX / Spinner not working properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku

My spinner show but only from the second search occurence on... 
When I search for a stock the first time nothing appears. Here's my repo: https://github.com/Ardzii/finance-tracker and the heroku: https://finance-tracker-ardzii.herokuapp.com/

And, so that you don't have to look the repo:

Here's the view: _lookup.html.erb (partial)

```
<div id="stock-lookup">
  <h3>Search for stocks</h3>
  <%= form_tag search_stocks_path, remote: true, method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form', spinner: true do %>
    <div class="form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <%= text_field_tag :stock, params[:stock], placeholder: "Stock ticker symbol", autofocus: true, class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-success") do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Look up a stock
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render 'common/spinner' %>
    <div id='stock-lookup-results'></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The spinner partial: _spinner.html.erb

```
<div id="spinner" class="row col-md-12 text-center spinner" style="display: none;">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin"></i> Processing...
</div>
```

My Javascript file: search.js.erb

```
var init_stock_lookup;

init_stock_lookup = function(){

  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:before', function(event, data, status){
    show_spinner();
  });

  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:complete', function(event, data, status){
    hide_spinner();
  });

  $('#stock-lookup-form').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status){
    $('#stock-lookup-results').html("<%= j render 'stock', {stock: @stock} %>");
  init_stock_lookup();
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  init_stock_lookup();

})
```

The view it renders: _stock.html.erb

```
<div class="well results-block">
  <% if stock.present? %>
    <strong>Symbol:</strong> <%= stock.ticker %>
    <strong>Name:</strong> <%= stock.name %>
    <strong>Price:</strong> <%= stock.price %>
  <% else %>
    <i>Stock not found</i>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My application.js file:

```
  var hide_spinner = function (){
    $("#spinner").hide();
  }

  var show_spinner = function (){
    $("#spinner").show();
  }
```

I'm not sure the problem was stated really clearly, so I will restate it here: 
The spinner works only after a first search. On the first lookup, I have no spinner being displayed...

Thanks in advance and as usual for your help!

Comment: You are using an Rails 5 App and have turbolinks active, so you need to be aware that document.ready its not gonna work . Check on [turbolinks documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) how to run your javascript when the page loads if you are gonna stick with turbolinks.

Comment: Hey Jorge! Thanks a lot for your reply. However, after removing Turbolinks, I'm still experiencing the issue... https://github.com/Ardzii/finance-tracker